# Need help to spot flaws in my java code

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a school assignment and I have the following question:

I am given a number of sticks (with distinct or similar length), and am tasked to find out the minimum number of sticks required to form a longer stick of given length.

For instance, 
Given 6 sticks of length 1,1,1,1,1,3 to form a longer stick of length 5, the output would be 3. 
NOTE: Sticks cannot be reused.

However, if it is impossible to form the given length, output -1.
For instance,
Given 3 sticks of length 1,2,6, to form a longer stick of length 5, output would be -1.

I have the following code, which have passed all public test cases. However, I failed the private test cases which I cannot figure out my mistake.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Result {
    static int min = 100000;

    public static int solve(int pos, int currSum, int len, int numStk) {
        // implementation
        for (int i=1; i<=Stick.data.length - pos; i++){
            if (currSum > len){
                continue;
            }

            else if (currSum < len){
                if (pos+i >= Stick.data.length){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    solve(pos+i,currSum+Stick.data[pos+i], len, numStk+1);
                }
            }

            else if (currSum == len){
                if (numStk < min){
                    min = numStk;
                }
            }
        }

        return min;
    }
}

class Stick {
    static int[] data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sticks = sc.nextInt();
        data = new int[sticks];
        int len = sc.nextInt(); 
        for (int i=0; i<sticks; i++){
            data[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i=0; i<sticks; i++){
            Result.solve(i,0,len,1);
        }

        if (Result.min == 100000){
            System.out.println(-1);
        } else {
            System.out.println(Result.min-1);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the desired outcome, the actual outcome, and the steps you've taken to debug the code.

Comment: What's a "private test case"?

Comment: **"However, I failed the private test cases..."** -- And those would be what, exactly?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: @azurefrog They're *private*.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually this is fine for SO.  It just has a horrible title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I notice about your code:

1. Bug: In main,

   `Result.solve(i,0,len,1);`

   assumes that stick i is taken (hence `numsticks = 1` in the arguments list), but currSum is given as 0. Shouldn't that be `data[i]`?
2. Better code quality: The checks for `currSum > len` and `currSum ==` len can be done outside the for loop, which is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out to be a problem with the starting currSUm.